Beacon detection failing with uuid in ScanFilter android
We’re using a ScanFilter in an Android foreground service to scan for beacons. The filter includes service UUID. When we remove the service UUID, we can detect beacons with the specified uuid. However, when we include the service UUID, beacon detection fails.
private var scanFilter: ScanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder()
.setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("0000feab-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))) // Filter by Service UUID
.build()

if we removed Service UUID filter we are getting below results for beacon we want to detect in onScanResult call back
ScanResult{device=CF:63:4B:5D:E1:F9, scanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null, mServiceSolicitationUuids=[], mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={0000feab-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[64, 0, 2, 11, -30, 0, 1, -49, 99, 75, 93, -31, -7, 48, 10]}, mTxPowerLevel=0, mDeviceName=0001, mTransportBlocks=[]], rssi=-71, timestampNanos=40980732284950, eventType=27, primaryPhy=1, secondaryPhy=0, advertisingSid=255, txPower=127, periodicAdvertisingInterval=0}

in above result mServiceUuids is null which i think is the problem, perhaps the beacon i'm detecting is not broadcasting service uuid, i can apply filter base on mServiceData like below:
  private val beaconUuid: ParcelUuid = ParcelUuid.fromString("0000feab-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
private var serviceData: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(64, 0) // This is the beginning of the service data
private var serviceDataMask: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(-1, -1) // This mask means match both bytes exactly

private var scanFilter: ScanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder()
    .setServiceData(beaconUuid, serviceData, serviceDataMask)  // Filter by Service Data
    .build()

I'm successfully filtering beacons using mServiceData with the current native BluethoothAdapter. However, I need to switch to the AltBeacon library for Samsung device compatibility. AltBeacon filters based on mServiceUuid when the samsung device is offline, but I can't find a way to filter by mServiceData using this library. Could someone please suggest a solution?
UPDATED
below is altbeacon configuration i applied
  beaconManager =  BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
    beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(
        createNotificationScan(), 1002
    )
    beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)
    beaconManager.backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = 5000
    beaconManager.backgroundScanPeriod = 11000
    beaconManager.foregroundBetweenScanPeriod = 1000
    beaconManager.foregroundScanPeriod = 10000
    BeaconManager.setDebug(true)
    beaconManager.beaconParsers.clear()
    val parser = BeaconParser().
    setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feab,m:2-3=4000,p:3-3:-41,i:4-21v")
    parser.setHardwareAssistManufacturerCodes(intArrayOf(0x0A62))
    beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(parser)
    region = Region("all-beacons-region", null, null, null)
    beaconManager.getRegionViewModel(region).rangedBeacons.observe(this, rangingObserver)

Detection works well for the mentioned beacons with the above configuration, but the same beacon is not detected when the screen goes off.
below is filter applied by altbeacon library when device screen goes off:
BluetoothLeScanFilter [mDeviceName=null, mDeviceAddress=null, mUuid=0000feab-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, mUuidMask=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff, mServiceSolicitationUuid=null, mServiceSolicitationUuidMask=null, mServiceDataUuid=null, mServiceData=null, mServiceDataMask=null, mManufacturerId=-1, mManufacturerData=null, mManufacturerDataMask=null, mAdvertisingDataType=-1, mAdvertisingData=null, mAdvertisingDataMask=null]


The Android Beacon Library does not use service data for its scan filters.  As currently written, it sets up a scan filter that includes only the ServiceUuid for Service Advertisement beacon formats like Eddystone.  (For Manufacturer advertisements like iBeacon and AltBeacon it sets up a scan filter matching the first bytes in the manufacturer data.)
The library code that does this is in the ScanFitlerUtils class here. AS of libarary version 2.21.0-beta4 and higher, service data is included in the scan filter.  (At the time the OP posted the question, it only sets up the UUID in the filter.)  But the filter must match BOTH the service data and the service UUID.
How do you make the library work for your use case?
If you know your Service UUID, that should be sufficient to match using the library. The sample code you show also matches the first two bytes of the service data (the Android Beacon Library currently does not support this, but could be augmented to do so. But you may be able to live with the filter just matching on the UUID and let the library programmatically check for the first two bytes).
Based on your sample code, I can see you are using a 16-bit service UUID of FEAB. So with the library, you would set up a BeaconParser like this:
val beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feab,m:2-3=4000,p:3-3:-41,i:4-21v"))

The above beacon parser expression tells the library to match your beacon like this:

s:0-1=feab Find service advertisements with a 16-bit service UUID FEAB hex
m:2-3=4000 Match the bacon only if the first two bytes of the service data are 40 00 hex (64 0 decimal)
p:3-3 Placeholder for the measured power value used for distance estimates in your beacon (you can change this to the actual byte position in the packet if you care about distance estimates)
i:4-21v Take all the remaining bytes in the service data and treat them as  a single beacon identifier.  If you want multiple identifiers you can split up these bytes into multiple identifiers with a more complex expression.

You may wish to tweak the above to meet your needs.
The library will set up a scan filter when the screen is off on Samsung to just match the 16-bit service UUID of FEAB.  But it will then post-process the detections to discard any that do not have the first two bytes in the service data of 40 00 hex or 64 0 decimal.
After setting up the BeaconParser as shown above, you can then use the library to detect these beacons and it should use scan filters as needed to detect with the screen off and in the background.

Thanks for providing these. I've updated my question to include the AltBeacon configuration. I’d appreciate your help in identifying what I might be missing.

Can you please set BeaconManager.setDebug(true) and attach an ADB brief log excerpt showing one detection in the foreground?  It may be helpful to also put the app to the background and look for the log line where it sets up the scan filter.  If you do the second part when showing system log lines (not just filtering for your app) you can see the actual scan filter Android sets up as configured by the library.

As of library version 2.21.0-beta4, service data is now supported in scan filters

Thanks davidgyoung, i'll try that.
